# Word to describe something both qualitative and quantitative?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word to describe my research process. I analyze large datasets, then interview people to understand what the data is telling me.

I'm struggling to come up with a way to describe this, some way to convey the combination:

- quantitative + qualitative
- art + science

That sort of thing...

Comment: It's OK to use two words, 'both quantitative and qualitative analysis'.

Comment: I'm not sure it gets any clearer and more to-the-point than your second sentence: "I analyze large datasets, then interview people to understand what the data is telling me." Print it on your business card! In all seriousness, inflating one's tone can reduce clarity.

Comment: Thank you, but I need this for a brand term. It's okay if it doesn't hit on exactly what I'm doing, as long as it obviously conveys duality (e.g., "yin and yang").

Comment: Asking for a marketing term is not usually considered topical.